# foreach elements values to different inks

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Hi I'm working on an simple online shopping MVC application.
I have a table that contains 3 categories: Laptops, mobiles, consoles.
I have a partial view that returns me these categories(from categories table) into a list,and I'm putting each value inside a button.

Partial View: _Categories

```
@model OnlineShopping.MyViewModel

<div class="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar" aria-label="Toolbar with button groups">
    <div class="btn-group mr-2" role="group" aria-label="First group">

        @foreach (Category item in Model.CategoriesV)
        {
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"> 
                @item.CategoriesName 
            </button>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm calling the partial view in the index like this

Index.cshtml

```
<div class="catmenu" style="display: none;">
    @Html.Partial("_Categories", Model)
</div><br />
```

I have another table called Products that contains the name of the products of each category and the category ID From the category table.

Example:

***Category table contains:***

categoryId =1

CategoriesName = Mobiles

***Product table contains:***

ProductID=1

ProductName=Apple

Category_ID=1

What I want to do is when I get the 3 categories from the Categories View
(laptops,mobiles,consoles),I want that if I click on the  laptop button ,it will take me to the laptop partial view and it will show all the products that have the same categoryID (like if I clicked on console i will get Xbox and PS because they have the Smaecategory ID as the ConsoleID), mobile to mobile partial view and same thing for consoles button.

I hope I was clear enough..
Thanks.

Comment: could you not just use a link instead of a button?

Answer (score 0):

do one thing, bind some unique id with the button in the first loop , i prefer the Id column ,so it will be like this : -

```
@model OnlineShopping.MyViewModel

<div class="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar" aria-label="Toolbar with button groups">
    <div class="btn-group mr-2" role="group" aria-label="First group">

        @foreach (Category item in Model.CategoriesV)
        {
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary catclick" id="item.Category_Id"> 
                @item.CategoriesName 
            </button>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

in the controller i will create a method which will return all items based on category

```
public ActionResult GetCatItems(int id){
  // method to return data here
  return View("_mypartialview",partialdata)

}
```

this will return plain html with filled data for your view, now you just need to paste the returned html at right place

```
$.ajax({
// ajax get data method
success(data){
  //on success clear the parent container of your partial view
   $('.catmenu').html('');


 //this will load your html into view
  $('.catmenu').html(data);
}
```

})

since in the controller we returned the view and caught it using ajax call, you get html of that partial view with your filled data

```
return View("_partial",data);
```

on success ajax get your partial view is rendered in the container

```
//on success clear the parent container of your partial view
   $('.catmenu').html('');


 //this will load your html into view
  $('.catmenu').html(data);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying, I did what you said exactly but it seems the  GetCatItems Method is not being called.

Comment: Thanks mate it,working now, I added value and name to the button tag and I created a Partial view that takes the id from the button like this:             <input type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" value="@item.CategoriesName"  name="CategName" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("GetCatItems", "Home")'"  />